# why event viewer is not opening?

Tags: asp.net, .net-framework, windows, windows-7

while double clicking the event viewer from Administrative tools I got the following prompt:
[image]

How to resolve the issue ?

Comment: It means `consent.exe` is crashing. Can you run any program as an administrator?

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like malware or something.
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-system/the-extended-attributes-are-inconsistent-come-up/129b7935-2da2-47b2-8b4d-e8b581e12b54

there are few other links that explains that this error might be caused because of virus or something. google the error message.